# Div impossibilitando jquery localizar próximo elemento

Tags: jquery, ajax

Amigos, estou com a seguinte questão:

O seguinte código abaixo localiza o próximo elemento a partir do select clicado:
https://jsfiddle.net/cmftasor/

Funciona perfeitamente.

O problema é que, ao incluir as divs filhas de formatação entre os campos, ele não consegue localizar mais o próximo elemento, mostrando-os como indefinido, veja o código:

https://jsfiddle.net/667qorya/

Qual foi o erro que eu cometi?

Comment: É isto que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/667qorya/1/

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que pude notar no seu código, no segundo exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/667qorya/ o `<select>` não está dentro da `<div class=".caixa-dependentes2">`  por isso quando você tenta chamar a função :

```
$('.caixa-dependentes2').on('change', '.aa', function(){
var proximo = $(this).nextAll('.bb').eq(0).val();
alert(proximo);
});
```

Não funciona, pois a `<div>` está vazia

Comment: Ola Luks, e então, neste caso, como eu posso fazer fazê-lo funcionar mantendo as divs?

Comment: Coloque ele dentro das divs.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorancia Luks, pelo que vi o select está dentro de uma div filha do caixa-dependentes2. isso é o que está causando o problema?

Comment: Tentei usar o parent -> "var proximo = $(this).parent().nextAll('.bb').eq(0).val();"  mas tambem não deu certo não

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar da seguinte forma:

```
var proximo = $(this).parents('.caixa-dependentes2').find('.bb').eq(0).val();
```

Comment: Ola Eduardo, testei aqui, dessa forma ele exibe somente os valores do primeiro indice.